# Is it safe to use third party OIDC ID Token as our APIs bearer token?

Tags: authentication, authorization, oauth2, openid-connect

Practically, we are outsourcing the authentication of our users to a third party application, that's, needless to say, external to our system. I am not sure if this is actually advisable, but from our perspective, since we don't really want to maintain security credentials ourselves, we thought that it makes sense to leave that to the hands of a more capable party. For now we intend to use them mainly as identity provider, because we find their authorisation support hard to use. To be clear, at the moment, we do not require any access to any other resources at the side of the identity provider beyond the user profile; the authorisation I'm referring to is for our own system. Because of this, acquiring an ID token from the trusted identity provider seems to be good enough for our purposes.

We intend to internally keep track of references to the user id provided through the id token (e.g. the JWT `sub` claim) for the purpose of attaching our own authorisation details to them. I'm thinking that since this is the case, because the ID token provides us enough information to be able to pull authorisation details about the user, we don't really need anything else. I'm not sure however, if this is a sound approach or there's a security risk in this kind of flow.

In this setup, for our own API we'd have to use the external IdP for authentication, but we'd probably need to be issuing the access tokens ourselves to our clients.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to use `ID Token` for providing access because that is not its purpose. When an application does authentication, it needs to to first **verify the identity** of a user and only **then allow access**. Verification of identity is done by validating the ID Token while access is allowed by validating the Access Token.

An `ID Token` proves "who is the user?". Possessing an ID Token does not mean having access.

An `Access Token` is a bearer token used to allow access **from a client application** (who has the token), **to a resource server** (who validates the token, e.g. an API), on behalf of the user (because the user consents to it - e.g. implicitly during login or after that).

Both of these tokens contain an audience (`aud`) claim that specified the intended audience for the token. The `ID Token`'s intended audience is the client who requested authentication (on behalf of the user). The `Access Token`'s intended audience is the **resource server**.

If the audience of the `Access Token` provided to you doesn't include your application, then you shouldn't use it for controlling access to your APIs. In this case, you are correct that you'd need to issue your own Bearer token for the API. However it is not suggest to use the `ID Token` instead simply because it is not its purpose.

Comment: So both our frontend and backend sytems are client to this identity provider and so we can specify an audience claim that works for both as if they're one and the same. I appreciate the difference between ID and access tokens from a conceptual perspective, but are there security risk in practice if we used the ID token as bearer token?

Comment: As long as there is an establishment of trust between your system and the authorisation server (e.g. a shared secret for signing the ID token as is usually the case), you are not worried about the differences in the contents of ID and Access tokens, the token lifespan is small, I don't see a security risk when it comes to authentication. However, you will have to deal with other challenges, such as renewing the ID token silently. I would still recommend to stick to the protocol rather than rolling out your own auth :)

Comment: What if I am using the Google Account as 3rd party IdP, but I need only the user data like email (which is "sub" by the way) and no required access to any other Google API (e.g calendar)?

In this case access token from Google should not secure my own API as Google is not my authorization server.

Comment: @BartoszRosa That is correct! It all depends on the audience of the token. In case as described by you, the audience will likely be only Google's own APIs.

Comment: I would also like to add another aspect: if you use an authentication "middleware" such as Okta/Keycloak/Auth0 and use OIDC to sign in, in this case the access token provided by the "middleware" should be used to secure the API.